# Requesting executors because tasks are backlogged

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have a spark streaming application that was running absolutely fine until yesterday and all of a sudden running into these warnings. I have the same environment and using the same code. Here are the warnings:

> > 05/09 17:13:03 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 16 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 31)
> > 16/05/09 17:13:03 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 19 new
> > executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 50)
>
> 16/05/09 17:13:12 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any
> resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered
> and have sufficient resources
>
> 16/05/09 17:13:27 WARN YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any
> resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered
> and have sufficient resources

I am using apache spark 1.6 on cloudera 5.5. quickstart VM. There are no applications running on the cluster to consume available resources.

Is there any config to be made?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469462/taskschedulerimpl-initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources). If that question doesn't solve your problem, please edit to explain what you tried and what happened.

Comment: Have you enabled dynamic executor allocation?

Comment: Yes, I added following properties     <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>spark_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService</value>
    </property> in spark-env.sh

Comment: Do I need any additional parameters to enable Dynamic allocation? I also added SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY, CORES in the spark-env but that did not help!!

Comment: @Abhi, you found any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The quickstart vm was designed to give a quick taste of the functionality, and is likely configured to 'fit in the box' rather than for long term stability.

In general, my recommendation for problems with sandboxes and quickstarts is to just set up a new one if it is needed.

In this specific case, the quickstart is for CDH, for which the successor (CDP) is already out.

CDP, the [Cloudera Data Platform](https://www.cloudera.com/products/cloudera-data-platform.html) is the successor to both CDH and HDP.

If you want to check out the latest version, there is a trial which should serve for most purposes that you may wanted to use the quickstart. This can be downloaded [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp/latest/release-guide/topics/cdpdc-trial-download-information.html).

---

Full disclosure: I am an employee of Cloudera, the company behind both CDH and CDP.