# Apache spark error while running with pyspark in a cluster

Tags: apache-spark

WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469462/taskschedulerimpl-initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources)

Comment: not yet still having issue